# RxJava/RxAndroid - Infinite Stream of Events from Sensors

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I have an app that monitors sensors for events, transform them and need to push upstream to the subscribers.

As an example, take location changes using `android.location.LocationManager`. The transformation may include using raw `lat/long` and `GeoCoder` to get the `Address`.

How do I model my monitor (`LocationListener`) and publisher?

```
class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
        //Get Address using GeoCoder
    }
}


class MetaAPI {
    Observable<Address> address() {
        return Observable.create({what}); //<-- What should I add here?
        //Need to glue MyLocationManager and MetaAPI
    }
}

//So that I can use like this -->
public AddressObservation {
    void monitor() {
        metaApi.address()
            .subscribe(...)
            ...;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Subject`'s for this purpose. This is just the main idea, without any design considerations (adjust to your case as you see fit):

```java
class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
        //Get Address using GeoCoder
        MetaAPI.subject.onNext(null /* actual address object */);
    }
}

class MetaAPI {

    static Subject<Address, Address> subject = PublishSubject.<Address>create().toSerialized();

    Observable<Address> address() {
        return subject;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me give a shot. As I understand `Subject = Observable + Observer` combo.

Comment: @MasterGaurav correct, the fact that `Subject` is `Observable` lets you return it as one and not expose this implementation detail to clients of `address()` method.

Comment: Yeah... that what I meant.